# Switched From EF 5 to EF 6 Alpha 3 - Now DbGeography does not work

Tags: entity-framework, spatial

I have this in my Domain

```
public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
```

and this in my mapping

```
 this.Property(t => t.Location);
```

Now in my mapping file I get an error on the above line

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType>.Property<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TStructuralType,T>>)'
```

Never had this error in EF 5.

Comment: Remove the reference to System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the solution that I found in the end after digging a bit further in to EF6 documentation.

**Removing assembly references to System.Data.Entity.dll**

Installing the EF6 NuGet package adds the following runtime assemblies to your project:

Recent builds of the EF6 NuGet package removes reference to System.Data.Entity.dll from the project.

**EF6 doesn’t use any code from System.Data.Entity.dll and having it referenced in your project could cause build conflicts.**

These conflicts can be resolved but in general you should not be using EF6 and System.Data.Entity.dll in the same application.

Hope this may help anyone else who faces the same issue.

Comment: Not a solution when using EF agnostic POCO objects.