# EF 6 Code First Mapping DbGeometry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, spatial

I've created a map file to map my class' properties to their respective database columns.

I have a database field called ptLocation which is a type of geometry. In my class I have it defined as

`public DbGeometry Location { get; set; }`

In my map file I have

```
Property(t => t.Location).HasColumnName("ptLocation");
```

I get the following error on the line above:

"The type 'System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T'"

Am I missing a configuration option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgraded from an earlier version of EF, be sure to remove the reference to System.Data.Entity.DLL, as per this [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638712/switched-from-ef-5-to-ef-6-alpha-3-now-dbgeography-does-not-work).